# Flutter project working perfectly on multiple emulators but fails to run on my phone

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a project that makes use of SharedPreferences, SQFlite, and Path Provider among other packages. The app works well on Pixel 3a and Pixel 4 emulators but does not run correctly on other devices including OnePlus Nord and Samsung Galaxy M33.

I was debugging the code and found out that it throws this exception:

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)`

On following the code flow, it was clear that this exception is called when the program encounters functions from the SharedPreferences, Path Provider, and SQFLite packages. I ran into this same predicament in both the devices. The Nord runs on Android 12L and the M33 runs on Android 12. It is to be noted that the Pixel 4 and Pixel 3a emulators on which the code worked runs on Android 12 and Android 14, respectively. I also tested the application on a Xiaomi Redmi 9 which runs on Android 10 where it works perfectly as well.

So I think that the packages are having some compatibility issues with my devices and I cannot identify what the problem is.

Both SharedPreferences and Path Provider produces the same exception that I included above. But SQFLite code on execution produces the following exception:

`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)`

Digging through the `sqflite.dart` file I found this implementation for the same method:

`Future<String> getDatabasesPath() => databaseFactory.getDatabasesPath();`

Google search and ChatGPT queries for the problems almost always resulted in following

`fluttter clean` > `flutter pub get`

or

`flutter pub outdated` > `flutter upgrade [outdated]` > `flutter clean` > `flutter pub get`

these or other combinations of these commands or included more hardwiring kind-of solutions where I would have to edit some Kotlin files. I did try it, only to produce more errors, but I think there is a more elegant solution to this problem. So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

PS:

Snippets showing code flow:

The following code is from the main file where I try to initialize the colors for the UI building.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Init State");
    appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    initializeColors();
    super.initState();
  }

  void initializeColors() async {
    final fileState = Provider.of<StorageDetails>(context, listen: false);
    await fileState.initializeDirectory();
    await appState.initializeColors(); //This line calls the function in a separate file that calculates and initializes
  }
```

The following code is from the second file where the color calculation and initialization takes place. The flow always breaks and throws the exception right when the getInstance() function is executed.

```dart
  Future<void> initializeColors() async {
    await loadColorsFromSharedPreferences();
  }

  Future<void> loadColorsFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    labelColor = Color(prefs.getInt('labelColor') ?? (0xFFE7B9AA));
    accentColor = Color(prefs.getInt('accentColor') ?? (0xFFD4582F));
    labelTextColor = Color(prefs.getInt('labelTextColor') ?? (0xFF000000));
    disabledButtonColor = Color(prefs.getInt('disabledButtonColor') ?? (0xFFD9D9D9));
    appTheme = prefs.getInt('appTheme') ?? 0;

    if (appTheme == 1) {
      setDarkTheme();
      print('DarkThemeSet');
    } else {
      setLightTheme();
      print('LightThemeSet');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem.

Create a new project and copy all the files in the lib folder to the new project's lib folder.

Instead of copying the entire contents of the pubspec file, list out the assets and the dependencies in the new project's pubspec file.

Similarly edit the build.gradle file to match the contents of the earlier project. Run `pub get` and test your project. It should work fine now :D